# not able to login with proper credentials

Tags: java, httpclient, autologin

I want to auto login into a website. I think the login url and the credentials I pass are all correct. Still my `entity.getContentLength()` shows -1. What does it mean?

The response I get is still the login page, not the page that I should get after the login. What might go wrong? Im using HttpClient.

Comment: What credentials are you passing? Username/password, x509 certificate, scan of your retina? After login, how does the site know who you are? Is it storing a cookie that you're not handling, for example?

Comment: im passing the email id/pwd and an hidden parameter that it expects which i see in view source page. Im not bothered at cookie for now since this is the 1st page. When i navigate to 2nd page or so i might have to handle cookie.

Comment: Without any code this is impossible to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the form on the URL you have as `input_text` you'll see that you need to post your login information to `/v2/login`. You're posting to the login page itself, not the login handler.

I recommend you first use Firebug with Firefox or the F12 tools with Internet Explorer and go through the login process, watching what gets posted where and what is returned.  After you understand the login process then try to recreate it in code.

When I monitored the conversation using Firebug as I advised above, I see the post actually goes to https://www.hautelook.com/v3/credential.

If you're using an older version of Java you'll have to configure HTTPClient to work with SSL as described here: [HttpClient SSL Guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html).

Comment: I used String input_text = "https://www.hautelook.com/v2/login"; and the response.getContentLength is now 20. What does it mean? response doesnt look like an html though.

Comment: ...and what about v3/credential?

Comment: Do you mean my code wont work if i just change the url above? Why is that i require HttpClient with SSL?

Comment: with /v3/credential Response content length: 20
HTML Content :::org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@80fa6f...I dont see any html response.